# Open-source Question & Answer website engine

Tags: gratis, open-source, cms

Which free and open-source Stack Exchange clones allow (as a standard feature) to show the first lines of a question in question lists and search results?

Like for example in TeX SE as in the following screenshot:

[image: TeX SE question list, where each list entry contains the first lines of its question]

Comment: Just for clarification: by "clone" you mean you want to setup your own SE-like site – or did you just confuse terms and mean an alternative client to access existing SE sites? Maybe you could [edit] your question and add a little more background, as well as lining out all your requirements (see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185))? Thanks!

Comment: PS: Seeing your other question ([Distributed Stack Exchange clone](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4596/185)), I guess the first of my mentioned alternatives is correct, and you're in fact looking for a clone...

Comment: I mean something like [askbot](https://askbot.com/) or [osqa](http://www.osqa.net/) and I want to run it locally but this doesn't matter for this question.

Answer (score 2):

### Check out [Scoold](https://scoold.com/)

> Scoold is a Stack Overflow clone written in Java

- It's [open source](https://github.com/Erudika/scoold/).
- You can [try the demo here](https://live.scoold.com/).

A screenshot from their website:

[image]

This is how a question in the feed, from the demo site:

[image]

And this is how the question page/post looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Askbot](https://askbot.org/) is open source Q&A system, like StackOverflow, Yahoo Answers and some others. It's using Django/Python and PostgreSQL or MySQL as a database.

Source: https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel

Documentation: https://askbot.org/doc/