# Distributed Stack Exchange clone

Tags: gratis, open-source, cms

Is there any FOSS Stack Exchange clone (like askbot OR osqa) with Git backend or more generally which allows me to do the following (for organizing personal knowledge in Q&A-format):

- Have a copy locally on laptop A and B (which should work independently offline)
- Sync/merge (easily) laptop A's and B's copies periodically when A and B have network access, with proper handling of conflicts etc.

Note that the main point in this question is to have good sync capabilities. For wiki software I know some solutions like ikiwiki. But is there also something for Q&A-software?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can get a Stack Exchange clone. Try [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/).
It is built by the same people who built Stack Exchange. It has all the features you are looking for except for the sync/merge option which I think you would have to do by a different way. Some of the features of discourse are:

- Free-open source : https://github.com/discourse/discourse
- Topics and tags
- Voting system
- Mobile support
- Attachments
- Users with different kinds of permissions

There is a piece of software called [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) though which makes syncing two databases which have similar or same schema easier. The software can find the diff between two schemas and will suggest insert update queries based on the diff. But the final change (sync) will have to be done by manual supervision.

Comment: Its a forum though. Very different beastie from SE. I DO seem to recall its postgres based, and there might be a few interesting live-sync mechanisms for that

Comment: Isnt stackoverflow a forum as well? I haven't tried syncing much with it I just tried it for fun so can't comment on that navicat though is something I use in work

Comment: Oh, hardly no. SE is a Q&A site. Very different thing that.

Comment: And what do people do in a forum? Ask questions I suppose? I agree SE is more organized than a forum though

Comment: forums have a single thread, or very rarely have branching threads. The way the content is laid out is the defining factor here.

Comment: Hmm...ok. Sorry but functionally I don't see too much difference between Q&A & forum(since they seem to solve the same problem) except the obvious fact that Q&A is lot more organized, like Q&A is Forum v2. If I have made a mistake I apologize.

Comment: @RamGAthreya - you have answered two questions asking for a Stack Exchange clone by recommending Discourse. That's not a good recommendation as far as I know. I agree with the comments above who say "Very different thing that."