# Forum software for q&a?

Tags: forum

I am the owner of a health site. Until now we only provide health articles, but now decided to open a Q&A section with use of a forum software. Because our site is on Wordpress we would like to use BBPress, but we're not sure enough. So I list some of our concerns and needs and would like your opinion:

1. have a good security
2. people can post without registration but there must be solutions for spam bots and common spam ways
3. post don't show up before manual approval
4. can monitor act of staff that answer
5. can noindex some of questions due to SEO concerns
6. lightweight

If it had related questions and a good search form it would be great, but that's not mandatory.

Comment: What would you say about something similar to this site http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4596/2401 ?

Comment: Do you want a forum (where users can discuss; sequential) or a Q&A site (where users can ask/answer)?

Comment: @Cornelius: That question is for **distributed** though.

Comment: Please be specific. A forum is something that has a "thread" and looks more like an email conversation. A Q&A site is something like this site where you have questions and answers, but not a conversation. Compare http://ubuntuforums.org (forum) against http://askubuntu.com/ (Q&A). Personally, I don't want to read through dozens of pages of a forum to find a solution.